# How does a PyQt intruction is proceeding?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

As part of my end-of-studies' project I'm working on a GUI which basically takes input values and run calculation from them. My issue occurs when I push the button which run these calculation. I want this button to be disabled during the calculation and its text to change for showing that the GUI is busy.

Unfortunately, these changes are displayed on the GUI only when the calculation is over, not before and even if they are called before the function that runs the simulation in the code.

Therefore I was wondering how these instructions are proceeding so I can maybe understand what's going on underneath.

Here's a short extract of the code if you want it :

I call the function 'onButtonClicked' when I push it

```
self.pushButton_simu.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClicked)
```

Then this (shortened) function calls 'displayGraph' which will do the calculation and display the results

```
def onButtonClicked(self):  
        if (not self.exist and self.simu):
            self.displayGraph()
```

Finally in this one I create a file where I put some values then try to disable and change the text of my button (which does not work immediately). Then I run the calculation with 'simu.simulation' and when it is over, my messagebox is displayed and so are my new text and my button disabled. Then when I close the messagebox the text changes immediately and my button becomes unable again.

```
def displayGraph(self):
        with open("Input_simulation", 'wb') as dataFile: 
                pickle.dump([self.planete.reynolds(), self.planete.reynoldsMagnetique(), self.planete.stuart(), int(self.label_Vnbmode_2.text()), self.spinBox_pasmode.value()], dataFile)

        self.pushButton_simu.setText("Simulation en cours")
        self.pushButton_simu.setEnabled(False)

        mode, wImMax = simu.simulation('Input_simulation')

        infoBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        infoBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information)
        infoBox.setWindowTitle("Information")
        infoBox.setText("Simulation réussie")
        infoBox.exec_()

        self.pushButton_simu.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_simu.setText("Lancer la simulation")
```

I tried to add a 'time.sleep' between setText and the beginning of the simulation but it doesn't work at all so I really don't understand what's going on. It's like it's too busy by the simulation to display the changes.

EDIT : I fixed my issue by using that thanks to rbaleksandar :

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I didn't because I don't know how to do that except posting the whole simulation which I prefer to avoid. I think that in this case it's more a matter of understanding what's going on instead of finding some bug or mistakes so a minimal reproducible example is not necessary imo.

Comment: Nobody has asked you to publish your simulation code, I have requested an MRE. If your code is small then it could be a valid MRE, but it is then the OP will have to work to create a new project implemented only the functionality that brings problems. IMHO is necessary since you indicate that according to your logic it should work but for some unknown reason (it could be presumed but I prefer not to do so) it does not work.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm just saying. I understand your point of view and I agree, My code is quite big even without the simulation, but you are right I should have made a little example with a function which takes time to calculate so the OP can run it without have to do anything. (Just in case for my previous post, I'm rather new here and I understand that sometimes it may be very anoying that new people who don't search by themselves first post here but I'm not one of them! I saw the thread you linked my post with and I tried the solution but it didn't solve my problem that's why I posted)

Comment: @eyllanesc Even though a MRE would be nice, it is quite clear what is happening here. Even without any of the code...So closing the question just because of that is not really a good move. Also it's not always possible to provide an MRE, as the OP  as stated, due to the clutter that surrounds the problematic spot in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the calculations in a separate thread. Otherwise experience exactly what's happening in your case - your button gets blocked (in fact the whole UI is) since intensive calculations takes all the processing time of your main thread, where also the UI resides (along with all things related to it like drawing, event handling etc.). If the thread is busy calculating your stuff, it has no "time" left doing anything else.

Typically this is done by creating a `QThread` and pushing (using `moveToThread(...)`) of another object to it, where you actual calculations take place. This object is called the worker, while the thread - the worker thread. You can then connect a signal from your worker to your button or the widget that contains it and disable/enable it respectively.

Alternative to that solution you can go for `QRunnable` with a slight modification to enable it to actually send signals (since `QRunnable` is not actually a `QObject`-derived class hence you need to explicitly inherit from `QObject` in order to use slots and signals).

Comment: Thank you a lot, I fixed my issue and now it works perfectly !

Comment: Glad to hear that.